# How to simplify this Jquery solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my Jquery at the moment:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var counter = 1
  $("tr td:nth-child(2)").text(counter);
  click ++;

});
```

Instead of using;

```
$"(tr td:nth-child(2)").text(counter);
```

I would like to use .slice() in order to avoid having to do this:

```
$("tr td:nth-child(2)").text(counter);
$("tr td:nth-child(4)").text(counter);
$("tr td:nth-child(6)").text(counter);
$("tr td:nth-child(8)").text(counter);
```

Alternatively if there is a better solution I would appreciate that too. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to set the text of all evens, just use `2n` instead of `2`. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Do you want to count the clicks on each element?

Comment: @Blender I got a counter with player names and beside their names is a counter that says 0. When I click the button I want the counter to be 1, 2, 3 and so on. In every tr there is 8 td's, and I want to select 2, 4, 6 and 8 so that the text inside them changes with each click.

Comment: @DuploW In that case you need to define your `counter` variable outside the `$('button').click` callback function, otherwise the value of the counter would be reset(to 1) every time you click on the button

Answer (score 1):

Try the jQuery [:even selector](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/):

```
$('tr td:even').text(counter);
```

If you want to start from index 2(and not 0), use:

```
$('tr td:even:not(:first)').text(counter);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/W94qH/)

Comment: @DuploW Because `even` refers to the index, which would be 0, 2, 4...and so on(which actually means 1st, 3rd, 5th element). You might want to use `$('tr td:odd')`

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the elements.

```
$("tr td").each(function (index, element) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) { // if you want to check for evens
        element.text(index);
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand what (index, element) does exactly, and the index %? Care to explain?

Comment: % is modulos -- if `index % 2 == 0` then it's an even number (index / 2 = whole number without remainder). `(index, element)` are arguments passed to the function, `index` is the numerical index of the specific element in the loop, and `element` is the element itself

Comment: @ChenAsraf Hmm.. Alright I'll have to look it up some more to fully understand it, thanks.